# Contact Builder | Exporting Mobile List | Empty File

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder

I am trying to **export Contacts** on Filtered list from Mobile lists.
This have around 80K records.
But whether I export as Browser export or chose to export to Enhanced FTP both resulting an **empty file with only Headers!**

I also tried to zip and export even that din work :-|

Anyone faced similar issue! Any workaround.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reference this article: [Export of a Mobile Filtered List results in an empty file](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000320441&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)

> An easy way around this would be to create a SQL Query Activity in Automation Studio which gathers data from your Filtered List and then writes to a Data Extension of your creation. You could then export that Data Extension to the FTP.

Comment: I confirm the above work around is best for this issue and works well... Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Workaround - 
Create a DE with the required fields and then write a query something similar to this -

SELECT Field1,Field2 from [Filtered List Name]

Comment: Thanks @Akash for sharing the SYNTAX of the Query to be used with filtered list.